# Error while trying to get string value with " : " from database and setting it in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is my code, I am trying to set the values from the DB to model but it throws error when getting the values which has ":" colon inside.

Error message:
Error: DataTip unavailable = error CS0726: ':' is not a valid format specifier

```cs
public static void GetApplicationSettings()
{
    Models.Constants.ApplicationSettings obj = new Models.Constants.ApplicationSettings();
    var con = Models.Constants.ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
        string oString = "SELECT [Key] ,[Value] FROM App.Settings";
        SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            PropertyInfo property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(rd["Key"].ToString());
            obj.GetType().GetProperty(rd["Key"].ToString()).SetValue(obj, rd["Value"].ToString(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

My class

```cs
public class ApplicationSettings 
{
    public string Secret { get; set; }
    public string BucketName{ get; set; }
}
```

Sample DB value

[image]

Comment: Please read up [Markdown in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: please share your ApplicationSettings.cs and current data on table

Comment: @thisisnabi have set with the class and the DB value

Comment: Why are you using low level raw SQL? Why not use Entity Framework? And `Models.Constants` sounds like global state. Why not use the `Configuration`? And you are using reflection to update properties? How did you get this code? Some tutorial or trial and error? There are much nicer ways to do this.

Comment: @JHBonarius can't use EF in the project and code is mostly made from trial and error.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to set ApplicationSettings.File_Storage_Path, and that doesn'texit. Also you aren't using the PropertyInfo you are getting.

Comment: SingleLine is Key and s3://dev is Value ??

Comment: @thisisnabi the File_Storage_Path is the Key and s3:// is the Value

Comment: The [description for CS0726](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0726) says it's an error in the debugger... perhaps you're specifying something inappropriate in a watch window?

Answer (score 0):

You must define File_Storage_Path  prop in your class.

```
public class ApplicationSettings 
{
    public string File_Storage_Path { get; set; }
    public string BucketName{ get; set; }
}
```